# Can you get shingles if you never have had chickenpox but got the chickenpox vaccine?

Tags: vaccine, chickenpox, shingles

Some sources say it's possible, while others say the opposite. The following links are just some of the examples. But in theory you need to have had chickenpox first before you can get shingles. Isn't that a correct statement? Thank you!

"[Some people who are vaccinated against chickenpox get shingles (herpes zoster) years later.](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/hcp/vis/vis-statements/varicella.html#:%7E:text=Talk%20with%20your%20health%20care%20provider%20to%20learn%20more.,after%20medical%20procedures%2C%20including%20vaccination.)"

“[You can’t get shingles if you’ve never had chickenpox, but it’s important to recognize the risks associated with the disease.](https://www.healthline.com/health/can-you-get-shingles-if-you-never-had-chickenpox)“

Comment: The source you cited is authoritative, so the answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Different sources say different things ...

Comment: Well, you didn't show us these other sources.

Comment: Oh, okay, Let me edit my question. Thank you for reminding me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDC and the FDA are authoritative sources.

As always you can check the [package insert for your particular vaccine formulation](https://www.fda.gov/vaccines-blood-biologics/vaccines/varivax-refrigerated-and-frozen-formulations).

In this case you need the *Description* section on page 8 of the package insert. The insert mentions that this is a live attenuated form of the varicella virus. To quote:

> VARIVAX [Varicella Virus Vaccine Live] is a preparation of the Oka/Merck strain of live, attenuated varicella virus

This means a weakened, but not inactive form of the virus. The weakening in general for vaccines may have been done through a number of methods, including genetic modification of the virus (usually removal of essential genes, depends strongly on the virus itself), chemical methods that weaken or even heat-treating to partially inactivate it. Which method is used depends on the vaccine. In the case of the VARIVAX vaccine, the virus is attenuated  by passage (repeated growth cycles) in human, guinea pig and further human cells. Unfortunately the paper is paywalled (I think) in New England Journal of Medicine, but it is reference 1 in the insert. I've provided a full reference below<sup>1</sup>.

The live bit means that you get an actual infection from the vaccine, just one that your body can (usually) cope with well and clear rapidly, leaving you immune to a full infection with a wild-type virus.  The live also means, that in some cases you might go on to get the second stage of the varicella virus infection, known as *herpes zoster* or shingles.

The insert even provides a reference for this happening:

> 11. Hammerschlag, M.R.; et al.: Herpes Zoster in an Adult Recipient of Live Attenuated Varicella Vaccine. J Infect Dis. 160(3): 535-537, 1989.

You can [read the abstract on PubMed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2547882/) for free, but I think full access is pay-walled.

So, long story short; you can get shingles from the VARIVAX vaccine.

Ref:

1. Weibel RE, Neff BJ, Kuter BJ, Guess HA, Rothenberger CA, Fitzgerald AJ, Connor KA, McLean AA, Hilleman MR, Buynak EB, et al. Live attenuated varicella virus vaccine. Efficacy trial in healthy children. N Engl J Med. 1984 May 31;310(22):1409-15. doi: https://doi.org/10.1056/NEJM198405313102201. PMID: [6325909](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6325909/).

Comment: Wow ~ Thank you so much for the explanation ! Now I understand why one can get shingles after getting the VARIVAX vaccine.

Comment: @Maurice Upvoting the answer is the best way to say thank you.

Comment: I thought by clicking the check mark is upvoting the answer. So what's the check mark for?

Comment: @Maurice The checkmark is for "accepted answer" meaning that the person who asked the question thinks the answer is the best/correct one. It still gives reputation (15 points) and I think it should also come with an automatic upvote, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation bob1! I think you are a very nice person :).